# React native cannot set multiple arrayitems from Firebase in loop

Tags: firebase, react-native, asynchronous

I am trying to get data from `Firebase` realtime database in the loop and set array items,
but just the last item can set.
it's looking like `synchronize` problems I tried a lot of things but couldn't solve it.

```
import FireBaseConnection from '../classes/firebaseconnection.js';

 const  getComments = () => {
    let cardatafetch=[]
     FireBaseConnection.GetData('/PostComments/1234').then((comments) => {
        for (i in comments) {
            cardatafetch.push(comment[i]) 
        }

 for (j in cardatafetch) { 
     var UserId =  cardatafetch[j]["UserID"]   

  FireBaseConnection.GetData('/Users/'+UserId).then((user) => {

     cardatafetch[j].ProfilePicture=user["ProfilePicture"] 
          })
        .catch((error) => {
           console.log(error)
              });
 }
       console.log(cardatafetch)

           }).catch((error) => {
           console.log(error)
              });

 }
    }
```

Console Output is

[image]

Same problem also during get images from storage

```
   for (j in cardatafetch) { 
  FireBaseConnection.GetImage().then((obj) => {
     cardatafetch[j].ProfilePicture=obj
          })
             .catch((error) => {
           console.log(error)
              }); 
 }
```

FireBaseConnection Class

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
import { utils } from '@react-native-firebase/app';

 class FireBaseConnection
 {
  static async  GetData(refValue) {
        let data;
 await database()
  .ref(refValue)
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    data =  snapshot.val();
  });
  return data;
}

static async  GetImage(imgValue) {
 const reference = storage().ref(imgValue);
 let imagePath= await reference.getDownloadURL().then(result =>result);
return imagePath;
}
}
export default FireBaseConnection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, what I have done is put your code inside last iteration of the loop so it will be implemented only once when all the items are pushed in the array.

```
import FireBaseConnection from '../classes/firebaseconnection.js';

const getComments = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let commentsArr = [];
        FireBaseConnection.GetData('/PostComments/1234').then((comments) => {
            Object.keys(comments).forEach((key, index) => {
                commentsArr.push(comments[key])

                if(index == Object.keys(comments).length-1) {
                    resolve(commentsArr);
                }
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    });
}

const addImagesToComment = () => {
    this.getComments().then((comments) => {
        var finalArr = [];
        comments.forEach((comment, index) => {
            var tempComment = comment;
            var UserId = comment["UserID"]
            FireBaseConnection.GetData('/Users/' + UserId).then((user) => {
                tempComment.ProfilePicture = user["ProfilePicture"]
                finalArr.push(tempComment);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });

            if(index == comments.length-1) {
                console.log(finalArr)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Try calling getComments function.

Comment: comments.length not working for json result. 
i tried      const   commentLength =Object.keys(comments).length for length 
it was okey for lenght but still same result.
just last item setted